# What happens if you send() to a generator *expression* in Python?

Tags: python, generator, send

I was surprised to find that, say, 
`ge=(x*x for x in [1,2,3])`
accepts the `.send` method. The argument of the first call must be `None`, as with any other generator , but the behaviour of further calls, say, `ans=ge.send(99)` seems identical to `ans=next(ge)`.

Where goes my 99? There are no yield expressions within ge, nothing to be assigned. Is the value injected simply discarded (as I suspect), or there is some Mystery involved?

Has anybody seen that?

Answer (score 3):

Same thing as if you `send` to the equivalent generator created with a generator function:

```
def genfunc(outer_iterable):
    for x in outer_iterable:
        yield x*x

ge = genfunc([1, 2, 3])
```

which is to say, the `send` argument gets discarded.

We can disassemble the bytecode for further confirmation:

```
import dis

ge=(x*x for x in [1,2,3])

print('Genexp:')
dis.dis(ge)

def genfunc(outer_iterable):
    for x in outer_iterable:
        yield x*x

ge = genfunc([1, 2, 3])

print()
print('Generator function:')
dis.dis(ge)
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/B8ZLF2):

```
Genexp:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                15 (to 21)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             15 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             16 YIELD_VALUE
             17 POP_TOP
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE

Generator function:
  9           0 SETUP_LOOP              23 (to 26)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (outer_iterable)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                15 (to 25)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

 10          13 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             19 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             20 YIELD_VALUE
             21 POP_TOP
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   25 POP_BLOCK
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

The genexp and the generator created through the generator function have very similar disassemblies, and in both, the `YIELD_VALUE` is immediately followed by a `POP_TOP` that discards any value sent in from `send`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes, which is also the same with a genexp or a generator created through a generator function. As mentioned in the question, the first `send` argument has to be `None`.

Comment: yup, just noticed that!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all. So yes, the arg of send is discarded, but the fact that send is *accepted* seems to be an anomaly.

Another, related bug has been already commented here (page 32139885), the yield expression should be forbidden in genexps, but it isn't. The form `ge=((yield x*x) for x in [1,2,3])` is accepted, and `.send()` works.

The answer returned by `send` is then a mixture of elements in the internal iterable, and the args of `send`... If I am not mistaken, GvR wrote that in Python 3.8 this (the yield expression) will be treated as an error, and in 3.7 it should signal that it is deprecated. (People agreed that it was confusing.)

But I tested that in Python 3.7 (Anaconda, Windows 64), and I got no deprecation warning. Anyway, this seems to be a real bug, not a feature to be deprecated. I believe that for the moment there is nothing more to say...

JK